# Date is converted to double when fetched from Worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, datetime

I have an application that manipulates data from an Excel workbook. In a given cell, I have a date in the format `"dd/mm/yyyy"`, which I need to display on screen. I use the following code to get it from the worksheet:

```
dateLabel.Text = excelApp.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(input, sheetToLook.Range["A2:G4"], 3, false).ToString();
```

Where `excelApp` is defined as `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp`, and `input` is a string to locate the correct row.

However, when I run the application, I get the following value:

```
Start Date: 43325
```

Expected result is `13/08/2018`.
What am I missing on? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: VLookup returns an object, not whatever Excel is showing after interpreting said object. Since you convert the Object to String, the application does not reinterpret is as a date. You should get the Object, cast or convert it to a Date type, and then use appropriate functionality to convert this Date to the appropriate display format.

Comment: Excel stores dates as sequential numbers. `43225` corresponds to `13/08/2018`.

Comment: Ah, great! Would any of you care to write this as an answer, and include each other's complement, so I can accept it?

Comment: Indeed, it's the number of days since 1/1/1900 plus a const correction for backwards compatibility with a bug (IIRC) if a date is later than a date sometime in the 70s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `DateTime.FromOADate()` to convert from an OADate (OLE Automation Date) to a standard C# DateTime.  In your particular example, `DateTime.FromOADate(excelApp.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(input, sheetToLook.Range["A2:G4"], 3, false))`.  You will probably want to add some data checking for the data that you pull in from that field, as `DateTime.FromOADate()` requires a `double` as the input.  I would probably code it as below

```
var excelDate = excelApp.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(input, sheetToLook.Range["A2:G4"], 3, false);

if(excelDate is double oaDate)
{
    dateLabel.Text = DateTime.FromOADate(oaDate);
}
```

Comment: For some reason, your code doesn't compile to me. `oaDate` is not recognized. Am I missing something?

Comment: @krobelusmeetsyndra Oh, yes, my apologies.  It is supposed to be a double, not a decimal.  Updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @krobelusmeetsyndra It should be noted that the safe cast pattern demonstrated above is for .NET 7 and above.  If you are using a lower version of .NET, you will need to find an alternative way of casting the value safely.